# Hashing or use SSL to send username and password to external site

Tags: php, security, ssl, https, passwords

I am working on a website at the moment, and I have coded the login boxes to login to another page (eg. login box on www.domain.com to login to subdomain.domain.com)

Subdomain uses HTTPS and at the moment domain doesn't.

My question is, should I hash the password and send it to subdomain to avoid using plaintext or should I require the domain to use HTTPS as well when using a POST request?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but I recommend using SSL for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing the password client side doesn't stop attackers sniffing "the thing you send to the server" and replicating it. Don't do that.

Using SSL encrypts communication between client and server. Do this.

Serving a form to the user without using SSL makes it vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks (e.g. JavaScript could be added that would steal the password as it was being entered and before the form was submitted securely). Don't do that.

When people want to login, redirect them to the secure site *before* asking them to enter their credentials.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will go back to the client and ask them which way they would like to go about it. Probably will enforce HTTPS on the main site as well as the subsite may be the answer. I didn't think just hashing would prevent sniffing.